# HTML5 video in Chrome doesn't support oncanplaythrough?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

Found few similar questions here, but still have no answer, and expect problems with new tag VIDEO. I integrated video into my page and want that it fires only after it cached enough to play without stops. Here is code:

```
<video id="intro_video" class="" src="video/myvid.webm" loop="true" autoplay="false" preload="auto" data-setup="{}" webkit-playsinline=""></video>
```

And JS that do two things: Play video when it cached enough and loop video:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var videos = $('video').each(function(index){
    $(this).addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
        this.play();
    }, false);

        $(this).bind('ended', function(){
            var video = videos[index + 1];
            video && video.play();
        });
    });
});
```

Code working well in IE, FF, Opera and Safari but not in the Chrome. In Chrome video start immediately and on slow speed connections it freezes each time.
Does any solution to fix this?

Comment: Sadly Chrome seems to be suffering from an over-optimistic buffering scenario (even youTube exhibits it sometimes). There's a sledgehammer solution in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video/18294706 but I'm hoping someone finds a smarter solution that works for larger videos than my kludge helps for