# How to fully buffer chrome video?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

While creating a video player using HTML5 video tag I have noticed undesirable behavior in Google Chrome. When I pause video buffering starts, and when I play buffering stops. As a result I get undesirable user experience.

I'm using large video files about 2-4 GB in size. And often, when I seek to some position and monitor buffered ranges I notice chrome buffers wrong buffer range. If I choose to pause player, chrome continues to buffer wrong buffer range and never buffers range currentTime is in and the one player is monitoring.

Another problem is that, since I choose to play video in background and hide viewer from noticing under other DOM elements, so I can force chrome to buffer while on playback. When is played / buffered enough I seek video back few seconds. Once I do this chrome **stops** buffering and my buffered range is quickly played, and process starts once again leaving bad user experience.

**Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround to make Google Chrome buffering continue and not to stop?**

Comment: You might wanna look at this question and the answers over there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video