# Play video in client side

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm developing a website using MVC5-html5(actually it will only has a limited number of user,may be 5-10 ). Now, I play video through video tag in html5.

```html
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="myVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

But in order to load the video, It takes time to get the video file from my server to clients and sometime it gets lagging. I wonder is it possible for me to let my client save these videos in their PCs and for the next time, we read direct video from there(let's say from C:\temp folder). Don't need to download from the server again.

Thank you for any though/ suggestion.

Comment: I don't think it will be any good. Try using streaming and some kind of js plugin for that. Or try to compress video. Also keep in mind that there not always are `C:\temp` folder (Windows temp folder is in other location)

Comment: play from youtube. give link. it will reduce load time

Comment: Justinas: Thank for comment,we can ask our user create that folder for us. So, We can make sure the video in that folder <br/>
PrashantTapase: That is a good idea. btw, these videos are private video, we dont want to public it into youtube, Maybe we have to use some kind of authentication set up.

Comment: you could possibly save the video as a blob in local storage (depending on size) and reload it on subsequent visits - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video?lq=1 for loading video from blob