# HTML 5 Video not buffer fully on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to buffer HTML 5 video on Page load using follow:

```
<video width="320" height="240" id="myVid" controls="controls" preload="auto">
     <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <object data="" width="320" height="240"></object>
</video>
```

but Video gets buffer only 40 to 50% on page load without playing and get stuck. I want to buffer full video on page load and then play.

Link : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKNeYQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another: Force Chrome to fully buffer mp4 video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video)

Comment: Listen for [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough) event

Comment: I tried preload="auto" which is not full-fill my requirement. I don't know how to use canplaythrough for this.

Answer (score 0):

The Browser itself decides how much to preload. You can not change that. Take a look at the table [here](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/) for more information. Some browser have a time limit some other a size limit. The only other option is to use a custom video player that supports your needs.