# Force Buffering in whole video while Paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I want to make the JWPlayer to buffer whole video while in "paused" state.

I used this according to JWPlayer API Reference:

```
playerInstance.getState("paused", function() {
    playerInstance.getBuffer("100");
    });
```

I also tried:

```
if (playerInstance.getState("paused")) {
    playerInstance.getBuffer("100");
    }
```

and lately:

```
playerInstance.on("bufferChange", function(callback) {
                console.log(callback.buffer);
                console.log(playerInstance.getBuffer());
            });
```

**This last one works with small mp4 video files, but not with large ones.
*And of course, I'm including JQuery library into my code.**
They aren't all working! I'm running it on Chrome, and the video files are large, I know about Chrome issues in download large video files, but come on, isn't there any workaround to bypass it?! I'll appreciate the support, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another: Force Chrome to fully buffer mp4 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer this since I cannot comment but having the same desire to force load/buffer the entire video so I can create a simulated highlight reel. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video) it looks like some hacks are needed since Chrome tries to pre-load as little as possible (presumably to save bandwidth usage). Basically use an ajax call to download the file to the browser then play that downloaded file.

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, posting links as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted. Or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.