# ASP.NET MVC video caching

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

In an ASP.NET MVC application I'm playing a video in a loop using this code:

```
<video id="video" name="media" class="container" preload="auto" autoplay loop   controls>
        <source src="@Model.VideoFilename" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

It works, but the problem is that the video is being downloaded from the server on each iteration.

The page hosting this video has this:

> Cache-Control:private, max-age=432000

The video file itself doesn't have any Cache-Control header in the response:

[image]

How do I enable caching of this video?

**EDIT**
I have added a web.config file to the folder containing the video and added

```
<clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="07.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
```

it added Cache-Control to the response, but the behavior didn't change.

**EDIT 2**
After trying several solutions which didn't work I ended up using this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294706/500105
which in my scenario worked good.