# Keep video stream in the memory

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have 1 video element on the page:

```
<video>
    <source ... />
</video>
```

I remove the whole *video* tag and create a new one (exactly the same). When I do that the browser download a new video stream.

Is it possible to cache video stream in the browser memory?

Comment: one way would be to load it into a blob in local cache (unless it's a huge file) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video/18294706#18294706

Comment: Yes, but the video can be really huge. It would be nice to keep only next _n_ bytes

Comment: Presumably you have the video marked as cacheable so the browser can attempt to be smart with the chunks, but if you're watching in network tools and still see it pulling from server you might have to delve into something like this - https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html - to manage the chunks yourself