# Too many https requsets when web Rqeusting just a single MP4 Video

Tags: spring-boot, video, video-streaming

[image: too many requests]

as you can see in the picture, the chrome has download too many clips of a video when playing a video online.

In rear end, I use springboot WebMvcConfiguer to filter the requests, when request url has '/files/**', it will let the request get the video directly
[image: filter]

how can i solve this request problem , and just make the request like this below

[image: correct result]

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include relevant parts of the code as Text and not as an image.  Also,  please clarify exactly what it is that you wish to do.  I don't know what the first column represents; but I'm assuming that the three lines in your last image represent different videos and you want to find the sum of the views for each video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to the browser loading the video over time versus all at one time. This is typically done for performance reasons and it doesn't seem like chrome likes people working around it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video) is a link to another post about the same thing.